# How to reformat and transform the output of jq?

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a json string as below:

```
    [{
        "appId": "server1",
        "userName": "bhavik",
        "scaleApp": {
            "imageName": "${DATA}/build-server:1",
            "internalPath": "/",
            "volumesFrom": [
                "${DATA}/buildtype-mock:219",
                "${DATA}/buildtype-se:543-1.0.5-V30.2-GA"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "appId": "server2",
        "userName": "rajiv",
        "scaleApp": {
            "imageName": "${DATA}/build-server:159",
            "internalPath": "/",
            "volumesFrom": [
                "${DATA}/buildtype-mock:218",
                "${DATA}/buildtype-se:540-1.0.5-V30.1-GA",
                "${DATA}/buildtype-nodejs:42",
                "${DATA}/buildtype-flogo:682"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I need output as below:

```
{
"imageName" : "build-server:159",
"volumesFrom" : [
        "buildtype-mock:218",
        "buildtype-se:540-1.0.5-V30.1-GA",
        "buildtype-nodejs:42",
        "buildtype-flogo:682"
      ]
}
```

I am trying to achieve it with jq. I am using the following command:

```
jq '.[] | { imageName: .scaleApp.imageName,volumesFrom: .scaleApp.volumesFrom } ' data.json
```

following is the output:

```
{
  "imageName": "${DATA}/build-server:159",
  "volumesFrom": [
        "${DATA}/buildtype-mock:218",
        "${DATA}/buildtype-se:540-1.0.5-V30.1-GA",
        "${DATA}/buildtype-nodejs:42",
        "${DATA}/buildtype-flogo:682"
      ]
}
```

I am not getting the proper format what I want, could anyone please help me out.

Comment: you want the output to be transformed, not just reformatted

Comment: It seems your fields have common prefixes you want to strip out. Well, strip them out.

Comment: how can we strip it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution to the original problem.  If the following filter is in `filter.jq`

```
  .scaleApp
| {imageName, volumesFrom}
| .imageName |= .[8:]
| .volumesFrom[] |= .[8:]
```

and the following (original) sample data

```
{
  "appId": "server1",
  "userName": "bhavik",
  "scaleApp": {
    "imageName": "${DATA}/build-server:159",
    "internalPath": "/",
    "volumesFrom": [
      "${DATA}/buildtype-mock:218",
      "${DATA}/buildtype-se:540-1.0.5-V30.1-GA",
      "${DATA}/buildtype-nodejs:42",
      "${DATA}/buildtype-flogo:682"
    ]
  }
}
```

is in `data.json` then the command

```
$ jq -M -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
{
  "imageName": "build-server:159",
  "volumesFrom": [
    "buildtype-mock:218",
    "buildtype-se:540-1.0.5-V30.1-GA",
    "buildtype-nodejs:42",
    "buildtype-flogo:682"
  ]
}
```

---

Here is a solution to the revised problem. Assuming the following sample data is in `data.json`

```
[
  {
    "appId": "server1",
    "userName": "bhavik",
    "scaleApp": {
      "imageName": "${DATA}/build-server:1",
      "internalPath": "/",
      "volumesFrom": [
        "${DATA}/buildtype-mock:219",
        "${DATA}/buildtype-se:543-1.0.5-V30.2-GA"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "appId": "server2",
    "userName": "rajiv",
    "scaleApp": {
      "imageName": "${DATA}/build-server:159",
      "internalPath": "/",
      "volumesFrom": [
        "${DATA}/buildtype-mock:218",
        "${DATA}/buildtype-se:540-1.0.5-V30.1-GA",
        "${DATA}/buildtype-nodejs:42",
        "${DATA}/buildtype-flogo:682"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

this `filter.jq`

```
map(      
  .scaleApp
| {imageName, volumesFrom}
| .imageName |= .[8:]
| .volumesFrom[] |= .[8:]
)
```

produces

```
[
  {
    "imageName": "build-server:1",
    "volumesFrom": [
      "buildtype-mock:219",
      "buildtype-se:543-1.0.5-V30.2-GA"
    ]
  },
  {
    "imageName": "build-server:159",
    "volumesFrom": [
      "buildtype-mock:218",
      "buildtype-se:540-1.0.5-V30.1-GA",
      "buildtype-nodejs:42",
      "buildtype-flogo:682"
    ]
  }
]
```

which is a little more then what you asked for so this `filter.jq`

```
map(      
   select(.appId == "server2")
|  .scaleApp
| {imageName, volumesFrom}
| .imageName |= .[8:]
| .volumesFrom[] |= .[8:]
)[]
```

produces only

```
{
  "imageName": "build-server:159",
  "volumesFrom": [
    "buildtype-mock:218",
    "buildtype-se:540-1.0.5-V30.1-GA",
    "buildtype-nodejs:42",
    "buildtype-flogo:682"
  ]
}
```

for `.appId == "server2"`

Comment: jq: error (at data.json): Cannot index array with string "scaleApp"

Comment: Sorry but whole json is in an array, because which it is giving this error

Comment: It is changed, you can see it now.

Comment: I've updated the solution to handle the revised sample data.